# How to get a stack trace of SQL calls?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a huge DB where a stored proc A calls stored proc B that calls C that calls function D, etc...  Over the years it has become a jungle.

Is it possible to get a stack trace of where the call is coming from? Without passing parameters or temp tables and such - just using SQL language.

Comment: SQL Profiler will get you a long way there.

Comment: @Laurence It it were only that simple.  The sproc in question must do different things based on the path the execution got there.  I know -  horrible design, but otherwise I am rewriting half the application.

Comment: You can fake some action at a distance with CONTEXT_INFO, but I think hunting down the perpetrator will be more fulfilling in the long run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trace T-SQL function calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352605/how-to-trace-t-sql-function-calls)

Comment: You can use extended events for this.