# Creating scalar functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have come across a situation where functions are very helpful. I can create it using its syntax and then I would use them in select or procedures.

But recently I have found that a function is called automatically when a row is inserted or updated. Also it is accepting two parameters. This user-defined scalar function is neither called in C# through ORM and moreover there is no stored procedure using this function, yet it is being called and as per my assumption, this setting must be in a table itself. It is triggered automatically when a row is updated or inserted.

Can somebody please throw some light on this as I have never encountered it before. An example of it would really be helpful that how it is created and how we can call this function.

Comment: It could be a default value on a column of the table you are inserting into.  It could also  be on a trigger.

Comment: Could you please add some reference or example of something similar. It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: It might be called from the trigger. The below  link might be useful. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I have tried googling and found the below url for the same. They have shown how to create a function as default value but how we can call this function as this function accepts two parameters.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442503/bind-a-column-default-value-to-a-function-in-sql-2005

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DEFAULTS_SAMPLE](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [CREATED] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DEFAULTS_SAMPLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DEFAULTS_SAMPLE_GUID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [GUID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DEFAULTS_SAMPLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DEFAULTS_SAMPLE_CREATED]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [CREATED]
GO

Comment: @Vincent: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can install SQL RedGate Search (it's free) which allows you to search all SQL objects to find where your functions has been used:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

[image]

Also possible is that you make a trace on that function to see where it has been called from (or at least by who):

[How to trace T-SQL function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352605/how-to-trace-t-sql-function-calls)